# Example pipeline from jenkins is not working apparently

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with Jenkins 2.190.1 installed and try to run the simple pipeline script

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this pulls the image and then it seems to get stuck and nothing happens, but the job is still proceeding.

When I cancel the job, the log says

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 122:127 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-pipe -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-pipe:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-pipe:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-pipe@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-pipe@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** node:7-alpine cat
$ docker top 154c572b654031349f2b338c22b932ced79339e48ad79a06e7665db1dfb9ae02 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh // here it seems nothing is happening and no progress is happening
Aborted by admin
Sending interrupt signal to process
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 154c572b654031349f2b338c22b932ced79339e48ad79a06e7665db1dfb9ae02
$ docker rm -f 154c572b654031349f2b338c22b932ced79339e48ad79a06e7665db1dfb9ae02
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: failed to run ps
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Decorator$1.kill(WithContainerStep.java:342)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask$FileMonitoringController.stop(FileMonitoringTask.java:345)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.stop(DurableTaskStep.java:512)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.stop(CpsThread.java:308)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$6.onSuccess(CpsFlowExecution.java:1151)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$6.onSuccess(CpsFlowExecution.java:1140)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$4$1.run(CpsFlowExecution.java:907)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.run(CpsVmExecutorService.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: ABORTED
```

What is wrong with my setup ? Or what could be the problem to look into ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Alpine Node container does not boot into a shell. You need to specify the shell in your script:

```
sh '''#!/bin/sh
    node --version
'''
```